# JAXB marshal Set<Object>

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I have an object similar to this:

```java
public class Obj {
    @XmlElement(name="value")
    public Set<Object> values;
}
```

When marshaling, this is generating an xml like:

```xml
<Obj>
    <value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">2009-02-14T00:31:30.001+01:00</value>
    <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">test</value>
</Obj>
```

However, I want to change some of that values (like the date format used for serializing `Date` and `Timestamp` objects), and also get rid of the annoying `xsi` attributes (but this is not really a requirement, I can live with that)

I've tried adding a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to `values`, but in the adapter I get the full `Set<Object>` to adapt, instead of single elements. I've also tried with a package adapter, but, as my `Set` is for `Object`, I cannot put the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type)` attribute.

Also, I've tried with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=MyAdapter.class, type=Timestamp.class)` to get only an adapter for the values inside that Object that I want.

So the question is, does someone know a way to get an adapter to work for this? Or maybe, change the date format every time a `Date` or `Timestamp` object is serialized?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` with the type property has to be specified on the package level. When used in this way it indicates that all usages of that type within the specified package are converted using the `XmlAdapter`. E.g. if you have a `package-info.java` like

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdaptor(type=Timestamp.class, value=MyAdapter.class)
})
package org.example;
```

Then a class in that package with a Timestamp field.

```
package org.example;
public class Obj {
    public Timestamp aTimestamp;
}
```

The specified adapter will be used to convert the timestamp. I suspect that this will work for your `Set<Object>` case but I haven't tried it myself.

The reason for the `xsi:type` attribute is that JAX-B likes to produce XML it can deserialize, so it needs to indicate what type it is or it could only parse everything back as strings. You can get rid of this attribute by using the [@XmlElementRef](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) annotation to create a schema substitution group, but in this case the XML will be produced with different element names. E.g.

```
public class Obj {
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type=String.class, name="string"),
        @XmlElementRef(type=Timestamp.class, name="timestamp")
    })
    public Set<Object> value;
}
```

Would produce the following XML structure if you had a timestamp and a string in the set. In this scenario the `xsi:type` attribute is unnecessary since JAX-B can tell what type to create from the element name.

```
<Obj>
    <timestamp>2009-02-14T00:31:30.001+01:00</timestamp>
    <string>test</string>
</Obj>
```

I would strongly recommend using the [@XmlElementWrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html) annotation to wrap up all the set items if you're going to take this approach.

If all you're after is a simple set of strings that you don't care about deserializing back to Java (or any other) objects with the correct types, then the simplest solution is to have an XmlAdapter that does just adapt the full `Set<Object>` into a `Set<String>` and handle the conversion yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was the first thing I tried, but with no luck. It seems JAXB (or my implementation, the default) is ignoring the adapter when the objects are inside a collection.  
Also, I knew about *why* JAXB is annotating my fields with `xsi` tags, but I only wanted to get rid of them. I can't change my XML, as it's already used in the product I'm trying to communicate with.   Thanks for your response!

Comment: In that case I would suggest using an XmlAdaptor to convert Set<Object> to Set<String> and handle the conversion yourself. I think that's the only way it's going to work.